# Path Problem in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to do the following
I am building asp.net website with c# language
I want to read a text file from my project(the file is inside the project)
I tried to get the file Path by this way :

```
string path=Request.PhysicalApplicationPath+"filename.txt";
```

but I can't use The "Request" object from separated C# file ??
note: separated C3 file,I mean it's not related with aspx file
can you help me with my way or do you have another way ??
thx

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you passing the path to your library from the web application. So for example in your web app:

```
var path = Server.MapPath("~/filename.txt");
var result = BusinessLayer.SomeMethod(path);
```

You could also use [HostingEnvironment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.aspx) in your class library but I would really advice you against it as it creates a dependency with `System.Web` which makes your class library tied to a web context and not unit testable friendly:

```
var path = Path.Combine(
    HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, 
    "filename.txt"
);
```

Comment: thanks Darin
But I faced the same problem 
I can't use "Server" object
from my C# file (this is my basic problem)

Comment: The first snippet I provided is to be placed in the Web Application where you have the Server object and **not** in the class library. You pass the path to the class library method as parameter so it won't need to calculate it.

Comment: thx man
The "HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath"
is what I was looking for

Comment: @Hany, please don't do this in your class library. I provided this just as an example but advice you against it.

Answer (score 1):

Using [HttpContext.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current.aspx) you have access to Request, Server, Response and other objects of the HTTP request.

Comment: Blech! It will also make the class nearly impossible to test.

Comment: @tvanfosson, I would say impossible :-)

Answer (score 1):

> but I can't use The "Request" object from separated C# file ??

I'm guessing you mean this is in a dll?
If so, then you can get to it by referencing system.web in the separate dll, and getting at the httpcontext.current object

Answer (score 0):

I would use some sort of injection mechanism either to give the application root path to the class or a copy of the current context/request to the class that it can use.   Essentially, you want to give the class the means to find the path (or even give it the path) rather than use a fixed dependency that is hard to recreate in testing.  To simplify my example, I'll use the Request as you are doing, though, you could easily provide just the base path of the application as a string as well.

```
public class Foo
{
     // HttpRequestBase may be more appropriate
     private HttpRequest Request { get; set; }

     public Foo( HttpRequest request )
     {
         this.Request = request;
     }

     public void Bar()
     {
          string path = Path.Combine( this.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath,
                                      "filename.txt" );
          ...
     }
}
```

Note that you could combine this with @Darin's ideas on how to calculate the server path as well.